# Obtener una propiedad de un arreglo

Tags: javascript, json, javascript-objeto

Tengo unos datos que están en localstorage, los cuales los quiero recorrer con un `for` para ir insertándolos en una tabla, pero solo necesito el dato de esa propiedad, es decir, su propiedad es numero `ot` y este contiene el número de una orden de trabajo el cual quiero mostrar en una tabla.
mi código es el siguiente:

```
//Arreglo de datos
var datos = JSON.parse(storage.getItem('ots'));


for(i in datos){

  console.log(datos[i]);

}
```

los datos que están en la variables son de tipo JSON son los que muestra la imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

por ejemplo si quisiera solo obtener el numero de la `ot`, debería ser algo mas o menos así:

```
datos[i].num_ot
```

pero me dice que no esta definido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo resolvi de la siguiente manera:

```
//
var data = JSON.parse(storage.getItem('ots'));

if(data == null){ return; }


//
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){

    //
    item = JSON.parse(data[i]);

    console.log(item.num_ot);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Como estás usando el foreach, estás obteniendo cada objeto del arreglo directamente, lo que necesitarías es solamente especificar la propiedad del objeto:

```
console.log(i.num_ot);
```

Answer (score 0):

No es conveniente usar `i` como nombre de la variable en un `for(variable in objeto)` porque esto lleva a pensar que `i` sería un **índice** como en `for(var i = 0; i < n; i++)` cuando lo que se asigna a `variable` es el nombre de una propiedad de `objeto`. Mejor usa `p` por propiedad.

Tampoco es conveniente usar `for..in` para iterar a través de los miembros de un objeto tipo Array, nuevamente porque es usual que lleve a confusiones.

Asumiendo que `datos` es un objeto de tipo Array, en lugar de `for..in` usa `Array.prototype.forEach()`

Ejemplo:

```js
var  datos = [
{num_ot:1},
{num_ot:2}
]
datos.forEach(dato => console.log(dato.num_ot));
```

- https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/for...in
- https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/forEach